# Trigger NSFetchedResultController only at saving time?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it a way to trigger `NSFetchedResultController` not upon change of `managedContext` but only at saving time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification of that managedContext and execute whatever logic you want when is triggered.